# Visual Studio Extension Reload Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I created a simple visual studio 2015 extension that adds a class to the current project.

```cs
Project p = (Project) ProjectsComboBox.SelectedItem;

string projectLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(p.FileName);
// I load the project where I want to Add file
var projectCurrent = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(p.FileName);


string relativeNewPath = "\\Model\\DAL\\" + ViewNameTexBox.Text + "DAO.cs";
string newPath = projectLocation + relativeNewPath;

projectCurrent.AddItem("Compile", relativeNewPath);
projectCurrent.Save();

// Once class added to my project I edit text inside newly create class
string text = File.ReadAllText("Templates/DAO.cs.txt");
text = text.Replace("$viewName$", ViewNameTexBox.Text);
File.WriteAllText(newPath, text);
```

The file is included to the project and modified but visual studio prompt a message asking to reload project. When I do so, the project won't reload.

> the project has been modified outside the environment

I would like to dispose currentProject but project is not IDisposable. Setting currentProject to null has no effect.

How can I tell my code to free currentProject and let Visual Studio reload it ?

Comment: Why the [tag:c] tag?

Comment: @IanAbbott miss click autocomplete, changed it to c#

Comment: I found another way to do it, see my answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44160484/1317323)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unload the project before add files to project, then load project again, The following code for your reference.

```
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection();

var projectCurrent = projectCollection.LoadProject(projectPath);
projectCollection.UnloadProject(projectCurrent);

string relativeNewPath = "\\Model\\DAL\\DAO.cs";
string newPath = projectPath + relativeNewPath;
projectCurrent.AddItem("Compile", relativeNewPath);
projectCurrent.Save();
projectCollection.LoadProject(projectPath);
```

[image]

Comment: Using this solution I have the project link file add at project root but the actual file in the right place (\\Model\\DAO). Also it offer to reload project but this time I can reload it.

Comment: Found it! relativePath must be "Model\\DAL" instead of "\\Model\\DAL"