# How to get list of possible strings when parameter is a string

Tags: c#, .net

In order to programmatically include a file to a project I use the method provided in this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23537007/1317323

Now I need to go further and add a xaml file and xaml.cs file to my project.

I need to know what would be an accepted string in the method `AddItem()` in order to include both files the right way. Something like

```cs
p.AddItem("Page", "so.xaml");
// or
p.AddItem("Xaml", so.xaml");
```

When I use the classic visual studio "right click/ add new item" way, I get this in the csproj file

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Page Include="example.xaml">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  </Page>
</ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="example.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>example.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

I read msdn with no luck.

I'm loking for a table that would give the value a the first parameter for a given item type or a way to construct such a table.

Comment: If it's a XAML file, and the root tag has an `x:Class` attribute, there's probably a .xaml.cs file -- but I can't say if you can guarantee it'll have the same name except for the ".cs" suffix. There isn't a grand table of these things, or a general way to deduce anything from first principles. When you add a UserControl (*for example*) to a WPF project, the wizard creates .xaml and .xaml.cs. The wizard that creates a Window does the same. When you add a resource dictionary, that one only adds .xaml. Personally, when user adds "foo.xaml", I'd *look for* "foo.xaml.cs".

Comment: ...or when adding "foo.bar", I might look for "foo.bar.*". Maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using another namespace from Microsoft.

The solution is based on this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22785353/1317323)

Instead of manipulating my solution with

```
 Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project
```

I use

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop
```

Now I manipulate

```
EnvDTE.Project
```

And I can use

```
_currentProject.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(path);
```

If I do it twice with a xaml and a xaml.cs file with the same name, there are automatically nested.